# pyuic5 - aviod generating connectSlotsByName() automatically

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I am using pyuic5 to generate py-files from ui-files (created with the qt-designer) this way:

```
pyuic5 my_form.ui -o my_form_UI.py
```

I have no signals and slots defined in my ui-file. So I uncheck the option 'Connect slots by name' in the 'Form Settings' (Form/Form Settings) to connect the signals and slots manually in my python code.

But after generating the py-file, I have this code in the file 'my_form_UI.py':

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyForm)
```

In the qt-designer I have also the possibility to save the form direct as py-file, the 'connectSlotsByName'-handling is here correct, but the generated module uses the 'PySide' package and I want to use 'PyQt5'.

I also would like to use this methode, because it is very handy to convert a bunch of files and use them in the python-ide.

Here is a simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMessageBox


class Ui_MyForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyForm):
        MyForm.setObjectName("MyForm")
        MyForm.resize(192, 86)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(MyForm)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.ui_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(MyForm)
        self.ui_name.setObjectName("ui_name")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_name, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MyForm)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ui_show = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MyForm)
        self.ui_show.setObjectName("ui_show")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_show, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(MyForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, MyForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MyForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("MyForm", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MyForm", "name:"))
        self.ui_show.setText(_translate("MyForm", "show"))


class MyForm(Ui_MyForm, QWidget):

    _name = ''

    @property
    def name(self):

        print(f'--> I am the name-getter!!')

        self._name = self.ui_name.text()
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):

        self.ui_name.setText(value)
        self._name = value

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.signals()

    def signals(self):

        self.ui_show.clicked.connect(self.show_name)

    def show_name(self):

        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Name")
        msg_box.setInformativeText(f'My name is {self.name}')
        msg_box.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    form = MyForm()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Explaination of the above code:

The class `Ui_MyForm` is the generated py-file from my my_form.ui. You can see here also the line with the `connectSlotsByName` command, although I deselected the option 'Connect slots by name' in the qt-designer. Here you have the content of my_form.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0" connectslotsbyname="false">
 <class>MyForm</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="MyForm">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>192</width>
    <height>86</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="ui_name"/>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="text">
        <string>name:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="ui_show">
       <property name="text">
        <string>show</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

When I execute my example, the command `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyForm)` calls my name-getter immediately.

I have only found this information about the issue: https://forum.qt.io/topic/134578/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-pyuic5-generating-connectslotsbyname-automatically

Is there a way to exclude the 'connectSlotsByName'-command in files generated with the pyuic5 tool?

Do I use the name getter wrong? (I do not have a broad coding experience)

Comment: The "connect slots by name" option was added in later versions of Designer, it's possible that the PyQt developer didn't consider it. I'd suggest you to write to the [mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) hoping that he will update the uic code considering this aspect. Note that, while I understand the issue (conceptually, a property shouldn't be recalled implicitly) it shouldn't be a real issue, unless you're doing something very peculiar in those getters.

Comment: Feed the monkey: `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName = lambda *args, **kwargs: None`.

Comment: Okay, I fed the monkey. I did it before ```self.setupUi(self)```, or is there a better solution?

Comment: @vezzon You could put it after the first import of `QtCore`: then it will work for all subsequent uses of designer UI classes.